# TwilioChatClient crash in CFNetwork/web socket, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, exc-bad-access, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using the latest `TwilioChatClient` version `5.0.0`

I got a crash in login function each time I try to login with access token, however this crash doesn't happen in quick start project provided by Twilio.

Here's what I got from symbolicated crash log.

```swift
Thread 5 name:
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d252da0 -[__NSURLSessionWebSocketTask _onqueue_enableWebSocketFraming:] + 468 (LocalWebSocketTask.mm:223)
1   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d252d94 -[__NSURLSessionWebSocketTask _onqueue_enableWebSocketFraming:] + 456 (LocalWebSocketTask.mm:221)
2   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d251ed0 -[__NSURLSessionWebSocketTask _onqueue_didReceiveResponse:completion:] + 2096 (LocalWebSocketTask.mm:663)
3   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d09ad04 __67-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask connection:didReceiveResponse:completion:]_block_invoke + 168 (LocalSessionTask.mm:1205)
4   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d071ce4 -[__NSCFLocalSessionTask connection:didReceiveResponse:completion:] + 280 (LocalSessionTask.mm:1149)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d10c61c __59-[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection _sendResponseToDelegate:]_block_invoke + 96 (SessionConnection.mm:1005)
6   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d10c5ac -[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection _sendResponseToDelegate:] + 120 (SessionConnection.mm:999)
7   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d0738e8 -[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection _tick_sniffNow] + 284 (SessionConnection.mm:796)
8   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d0778dc -[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection _tick] + 324 (SessionConnection.mm:812)
9   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d072d0c -[__NSCFURLLocalSessionConnection _didFinishWithError:] + 236 (SessionConnection.mm:1190)
10  CFNetwork                       0x000000018d10d9fc invocation function for block in SessionConnectionLoadable::withLoaderClientAsync(void (LoaderClientInterface*) block_pointer) + 28 (SessionConnection.mm:91)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c6763e4 0x18c666000 + 66532
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c6c7298 0x18c666000 + 397976
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c66fa40 0x18c666000 + 39488
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c670548 0x18c666000 + 42312
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c679fac 0x18c666000 + 81836
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4edd5bc _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2437)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4ee086c start_wqthread + 8
```

I have contacted the support but we couldn't find the real reason behind the crash. Unfortunately, it's not open source, so I couldn't debug the crash inside the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I found that there is another pod conflicting with this one called [`Netfox`](https://github.com/kasketis/netfox)

I believe that both are using web sockets and somehow they were conflicted with each other.

Comment: it was `Wormholy` for me. Removed it, problem solved.